# JWT validation - sts.windows.net vs login.windows.net: Why are the issuers not consistent?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-functions

I am developing an application that is spread across multiple `Function App` running on `.net5`.

I need to authenticate HTTP calls between functions. To do so, I am using `Azure Active Directory`. I have created a registered application in my tenant and generated a new secret. Whenever *Function1* needs to contact *Function2*, I retrieve an access token from AAD, like this:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={Uri.EscapeUriString(clientId)}&client_secret={Uri.EscapeUriString(clientSecret)}&scope={Uri.EscapeUriString(scope)}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             
string tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/57cc008d-ba7c-4887-acfd-93089c705640/oauth2/v2.0/token";
           
HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.PostAsync(tokenUrl, stringContent);
                    
string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

With this call, I get a token which has the following information:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX_KXEg",
  "kid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX_KXEg"
}.{
  "aud": "api://f87cc6ac-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/57cc008d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/",
  "iat": 1628443017,
  "nbf": 1628443017,
  "exp": 1628446917,
  "aio": "E2ZgYOg4qv7qZsTRKv5v+XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "appid": "f87cc6ac-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/57cc008d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/",
  "oid": "39b2e6b8-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "rh": "0.AVsAjQDMV3y6h0is_ZMInHBWQKzGfPhOtBZEj3l003jzIFFbAAA.",
  "sub": "39b2e6b8-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "tid": "57cc008d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "uti": "U7pMFAzw_XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

Now, the access token is used as a bearer token when *Function2* is called. *Function2* gets the token from the `Authorization` header and tries to validate it, like this:

```
ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ("https://login.microsoftonline.com/57cc008d-ba7c-4887-acfd-93089c705640/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
    
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConnectConfiguration = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
    
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuers = new[]
    {
        openIdConnectConfiguration.Issuer
    },
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConnectConfiguration.SigningKeys,
    RequireExpirationTime = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    RequireSignedTokens = true,
};
    
JwtSecurityTokenHandler securityTokenHandler = new();
    
if (!securityTokenHandler.CanReadToken(cleanedBearerToken))
    throw new ArgumentException("Unable to read the token. It is malformed.");
    
try
{
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = securityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(cleanedBearerToken, validationParameters, out SecurityToken _);
    
    return claimsPrincipal;
}
catch (Exception unhandledException)
{
    throw new AuthenticationException("The token could not be validated.", unhandledException);
}
```

Aside from the issuer, the validation works. With this setup, the issuer can't be validated. The token indicates that the issuer is from `sts.windows.net`. However, the OpenID configuration states that the issuer must be `login.microsoft.com`.

To make it work, I have fall back to something like this which is less ideal since I have to ignore a parameter returned by the `openid-configuration` endpoint (which *must* know better that I):

```
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuers = new[]
    {
        // --> Force the use of the following issuer!!
        "https://sts.windows.net/57cc008d-ba7c-4887-acfd-93089c705640/"
    },
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConnectConfiguration.SigningKeys,
    RequireExpirationTime = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    RequireSignedTokens = true,
};
```

**Question**

Is the override of issuer a good practice? If not, what can I do to get consistent issuer from Azure Active Directory and avoid specifying the issuer myself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issuer value depends on the Access token version. If you view the [Sample Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#sample-tokens) in jwt.ms, you will see the issuer for Access token V1 is `https://sts.windows.net/...` and for Access token V2 it is `https://login.microsoft.com/...`

Also, if you check OIDC metadata endpoint v1 (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration), issuer will be `sts.windows.net` and for OIDC metadata endpoint v2 (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration), issuer will be `login.microsoft.com`.

**Update**

In registered application's manifest, look for the value of `accessTokenAcceptedVersion`:

[image]

Change it to 2 and the issuer will become `login.microsoft.com` instead of `sts.windows.net`.

[image]

Comment: The token is queried from 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?nonce={{$randomUUID}}&response_mode=query` and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/57cc008d-ba7c-4887-acfd-93089c705640/oauth2/v2.0/token` so I am not sure why it still returns `sts.windows.net` as the issuer...

Comment: I was referring to the version of access token (the ver claim in the access token), not the oauth2/v2.0 endpoint. You can get token with "ver": "1.0" from the oauth2/v2.0 endpoint.

Comment: Understood. Is there a way for me to request version 2 of the access token (which I assume will be issued by `login.microsoft.com`) or is it controlled by Microsoft?

Comment: This depends on the value of "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" parameter in the Manifest of the API/resource you request the token for. E.g. if you request an access token for API1 whose accessTokenAcceptedVersion is set to null or 1, you will get access token v1.0, if you change accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2, the token version will be v2.0. So it is configurable only when you have access to the manifest of the api/resource for which the token is to be acquired. Read More: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute

Comment: Right on :) In the manifest, I did see the null set for the accessTokenAcceptedVersion. I changed it to 2 and it worked! I have updated the answer to include these steps which I believe are crucial. Thank you!!

Comment: Weird, MS was setting the version to null if I restricted the access to current tenant only, but will set it to 2 if I allowed it to everyone. Changing manually in the manifest fixed the issue.